# Angular 12 display components one by one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have an array of words, and I want to display each word, one by one, through the card component.
How can I display only one card component at the time, and jump to the next one by clicking?

(*I want to generate all of the cards with their specific words, not just change the words in a single card.*)

Comment: Can you provide more information about it? Sample of your words, code of your card etc.

Comment: perhaps ion-slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be close to what you are looking for? You would then need to animate the transitions between the hide and show classes to get the 'jump' you mention:

```html
<div 
  *ngFor="let word of wordArray, let i = index" 
  [class.show]="selectedCard === i" 
  [class.hide]="selectedCard !== i"
  (click)="onCardClick(i)"
>
  {{ word }}
</div>
```

```js
selectedCard: number = 0

onCardClick(id: number): void{
   this.selectedCard = id + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a component called `"app-card-component"`?

I'm not sure what your level of understanding is so I'm going to keep it really simple.

When showing components with arrays, typically you'd use `*ngFor`. So in this instance it could be:

```
<app-card-component *ngFor="let card of oneByOneArray; index as i"><app-card-component>
```

*(oneByOneArray being the array you push words to; one by one).*

To show these words one by one I would use a seperate array to push these words to on click.

On click you can take the `i` we now defined as index in our `*ngFor`, to lookup the next word we would like to push to our oneByOneArray.

So a function to do this can look like this:

```
pushWordWithIndex(i) {
   this.oneByOneArray.push(this.originalArray[i] + 1);
}
```

Now you can add a click event to the card like so:

```
<app-card-component *ngFor="let card of oneByOneArray; index as i" (click)="pushWordWithIndex(i)"><app-card-component>
```

Quick tip:

You should initiate the pushWordWithIndex function on ngOnInit or it won't show any cards ofcourse. `this.pushWordWithIndex(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Roy respose maybe it could be something like this

**HTML**

```
<app-card-component *ngFor="let card of oneByOneArray"><app-card-component>    
<button (click)="nextWord()"></button>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'wordN']
const oneByOneArray = [];

nextWord(){
   this.oneByOneArray.push(words.pop());
}
```